# forward declaration generates incompatible type error

Tags: c++

I've been reading some on forward declarations, including in this forum. They all say that it saves us from including the header file, However the following code generates an error:

```
#ifndef CLASSA_H_
#define CLASSA_H_

class B;

class A {

public:
    A();
    ~A();
    int getCount();
private:
    static int _count;
    int _num;
    B _b1;   //ERROR

};
```

compiler says:
`A.h:23: error: field ‘_b1’ has incomplete type`

I noticed that if i make `_b1` of type `B*` the problem is solved.

So is forward declaration good only for pointer types?
If i want `A` to hold `B` object i have to `#inlcude "B.h"` ?

thanks!

Comment: A bit of self-promotion: here is an answer that explains [what you can and cannot do with incomplete types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/553682/when-to-use-forward-declaration/553869#553869) (i.e. types that are declared but not yet defined).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The compiler has to know the exact definition of class `B` to determine at least what size to give to class `A`. If you use a pointer, it knows its size.

Note that circular dependencies are not possible. If you want

```
class A { B b; };
class B { A a; };
```

then A and B must have infinite size...

Answer (score 6):

You can use ***a forward-declared type*** to

1. use pointers and references to it as data members
2. use it as an argument (even taking per copy) or return type (even returning per copy) for function *declarations*.

You will need ***a full definition of a type*** in order to

1. use it as class data member
2. use it in function *definitions*.

If you remember that a forward-declaration actually is a misnomed *declaration* ([there is no other way of *declaring* a class type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410563/what-is-the-difference-between-a-definition-and-a-declaration/1410632#1410632), so *any declaration* of a class type is a forward declaration), and that, whenever you are opening the braces after `class`/`struct`/`union` plus identifier, you are *defining* a class, all you need to remember is that you:

- need a full definition to use the type itself in definitions
- get away with only a declaration to use the type itself in declarations
- get away with only a declaration when you use only pointers and references and do not try to access members or nested types (anything with `.`, `->`, and `::` in front)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would have to

```
#include "B.h"
```

if you want to include B in your class A.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, forward declarations work only if you use Pointers and References to the forward-declared type. If you use the object by value, you need to include the complete header file.

Comment: Well, forward declarations would work for using it as a type in function _declarations_, too: `B f(B);` You need the full definition of `B` to actually _define_ this function, though.