# create a std container of template class within itself

Tags: c++, templates, stl

I have the following inheritance hierarchy of class templates:

```
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

// Basic class template
template <class T>
class Data
{
public:
  ~Data();
  Data();

protected:
  T data;
};

// Works with no problems
class String : public Data <std::string>
{

};

// Works with no problems
class Float : public Data <float>
{

};

// Compilation error
class Object : public Data < std::unordered_map < std::string, Data < Object > > >
{

};
```

I'm trying to create an std container of a class I'm currently defining. Is this possible? If this wasn't a class template, I could of did a forward declaration, but since it's a template, any chance of this working?

Comment: "Problem :(" is not a valid question, or an actual problem description. P.S. Fix your assignment operator. It results in undefined behavior, in many use cases.

Comment: `Object` is not a template.

Comment: It actually compiles in clang: http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/BfBEnLjY16Oa6EZ5

Comment: g++: `try.cc:13:5: error: ‘Data<T>::data’ has incomplete type` because it thinks `Object` is incomplete at that point.

Comment: Ok, actually the problem is with Data < Object >, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3823464/2004616

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the `std::unordered_map < std::string, Data < Object > >` `Object` is an incomplete type

You can use pointer to `Object` instead:

```
class Object : public Data <   std::unordered_map < std::string, Object* >>
{

};
```